# How can I get Variety working on Hyprland?

Tags: linux, background, tiling, arch

I'm trying to use Variety in Hyprland, but I haven't found an article or a Question anywhere on the web.

Can anyone tell me how I can integrate it in my hyprland.conf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As detailed here https://www.lorenzobettini.it/2023/05/hyprland-and-the-variety-wallpaper-manager/ you must first install `swaybg` and then you edit the file `~/.config/variety/scripts/set_wallpaper` by changing the line

```bash
if [[ -n $SWAYSOCK ]]; then
```

into something like

```bash
if [[ -n $SWAYSOCK || $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP == "Hyprland" ]] ; then
```

or simply (if you don't plan to use "sway")

```bash
if [[ $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP == "Hyprland" ]] ; then
```

Now, Variety can change your wallpaper.